# Bind Dynamic Column Values to an Object

Tags: java, algorithm, binding

In Java, I am trying to map values of a delimited `String` to an object which their order can alter from each request. The order is implicitly known, in other word, I know the expected delimited String should come back with certain order. Assuming the following binding Object:

```
public class BinderObj {
  private String prop1;
  private String prop2;
  private int prop3;
  private String prop4;
  private String prop5;
  private String prop6;
  private String prop7;
  private String prop8;

  public void setProp1(String prop1) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
  }
  public void setProp2(String prop2) {
    this.prop2 = prop2;
  }
  public void setProp3(int prop3) {
    this.prop3 = prop3;
  }
  public void setProp4(String prop4) {
    this.prop1 = prop4;
  }

  // ...
}
```

If I receive the following request (comma delimited String), which at the time when I receive the delimited string list, I know the order of the values:

```
(Column2,Column5,Column3,Column7) <-- implicit information in which we know the order of values that should be mapped to what property
Johnson,Asian,27,000009
```

This should end up being bounded to the following properties:

```
BindingObj obj = new BindingObj();
obj.setProp2("Johnson");
obj.setProp5("Asian");
obj.setProp3(27);
obj.setProp7("000009");
```

And with the following order:

```
(Column6,Column1,Column3,Column4) <-- implicit information in which we know what the order of values should map to what property
UDD93,John,20,021980DE
```

This should end up setting the following properties:

```
BindingObj obj = new BindingObj();
obj.setProp6("UDD93");
obj.setProp1("John");
obj.setProp3(20);
obj.setProp4("021980DE");
```

Is there a clean way to set the appropriate properties other than brute force checking each implicit column, which we know before hand that dictates the order of values received?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the order of the columns, you could have one method that has two arguments: the input String (not split by the comma delimiter), and the indexes of each respective value (essentially a parallel array). From there, you can run each method accordingly. In the main class, it could look something like these options...

```
BindingObj obj = new BindingObj();
obj.setProps("Johnson,Asian,27,000009","2,5,3,7");
```

```
BindingObj obj = new BindingObj();
int[] columns = {2,5,3,7}; 
obj.setProps("Johnson,Asian,27,000009", columns);
```

It could be implemented like this...

```
public void setProps(String arg, int[] indexes){
  //creates arguments based on comma delimiter
  String[] args = arg.split(",");
  //counter
  int c=0;
  //runs through passed in indexes
  for(int index : indexes){
    switch(index){
       case 1:
         setProp1(args[c]);
         c++;
         break;
       case 2:
         setProp2(args[c]);
         c++;
         break;
       case 3:
         setProp3(args[c]);
         c++;
         break;
       case 4:
         setProp4(args[c]);
         c++;
         break;
       case 5:
         setProp5(args[c]);
         c++;
         break;
       case 6:
         setProp6(args[c]);
         c++;
         break;
       case 7:
         setProp7(args[c]);
         c++;
         break;
       case 8:
         setProp8(args[c]);
         c++;
         break;
    }
  }
}
```

This example is somewhat repetitive unfortunately. One way to fix this would be to find patterns in the format of each column that identify which prop it is. For example, it appears prop3 has a format of a 2 digit int. I don't know enough about your circumstance to give this kind of answer to you, but it's certainly worth considering on your own.

Comment: Thanks John. Unfortunately, this is a type of brute force I wanted to avoid. The values also do not follow any explicit pattern so they can be distinguished.